# Hide status bar automatically

Tags: flutter, statusbar

I've seen a lot of topics that answer this but none that do it automatically, my status bar hides when I open the application but when I bring it up it doesn't want to hide.

does anyone know the solution?

(I put this in the main: `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom])`).

Answer (score 0):

I did not used before but you can try [flutter_statusbar_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbar_manager)

there is setHidden function and height property probably these two will do what you want